Villager goes to learn kung-fu, can't afford tuition
I saw the beginning of a Chinese kung-fu movie on cable (USA Network?) in the late 80's or early 90's, and always wanted to see the rest. However, I have no idea who stars nor the name.
Here's what I recall:
Some peasant villagers were tired of being suppressed, so they chose one young man to go to kung-fu school. He showed up at school and asked to learn, but is refused as he has no money for tuition. 
The kung-fu school master has him work to earn tuition, and he builds a scaffolding out of bamboo, all while observing the students as they learn. He inadvertently learns while working. When he is done working, the master fights him through an obstacle course, and sends him home without formal enrollment.
He returns home, and the other villagers are enraged and attack him; several men grab him, and he proceeds to fight and easily defeat them all. He is surprised at how he can do this as he was unaware of his learning.
I'm fairly certain it was Chinese and kung-fu, but I am not 100% certain.

Not very sure : Kung Fu Hustle ?

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068000/ - not quite what you are describing, but have similar points.

@MahmadLebowski Kung Fu Hustle is a really fun movie! But this plotline is different.
